# scrapy don't give me an error but don't excute my code either

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

why when I crawl this code trying to get the title, author and lenght

```
import scrapy
HTTPCACHE_ENABLED = False

class AudibleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "audible"
    allowed_domains = ["www.audible.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.audible.com/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        product_container=response.xpath('//div[@class="adbl-impression-container "]/div/span/ul/li')
        for product in product_container:

            book_title=product.xpath('./div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/span/ul/li[1]/h3/a/text()').get()
            book_author=product.xpath('./div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/span/ul/li[3]/span/a/text()').getall()
            book_len=product.xpath('./div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/span/ul/li[5]/span/text()').get()
            
            yield{
                'auther':book_author,
                'lenghth':book_len,
                'title':book_title,
            }
```

it gives me :

```
2023-02-04 22:50:23 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.8.0 started (bot: spider_new)
2023-02-04 22:50:23 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.9.2.0, libxml2 2.9.12, cssselect 1.2.0, parsel 1.7.0, w3lib 2.1.1, Twisted 22.10.0, Python 3.11.1 (tags/v3.11.1:a7a450f, Dec  6 2022, 19:58:39) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 23.0.0 (OpenSSL 3.0.7 1 Nov 2022), cryptography 39.0.0, Platform Windows-10-10.0.19044-SP0
2023-02-04 22:50:23 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'spider_new',
 'FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING': 'utf-8',
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'spider_new.spiders',
 'REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION': '2.7',
 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True,
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['spider_new.spiders'],
 'TWISTED_REACTOR': 'twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor'}
2023-02-04 22:50:23 [asyncio] DEBUG: Using selector: SelectSelector
2023-02-04 22:50:23 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor
2023-02-04 22:50:23 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using asyncio event loop: asyncio.windows_events._WindowsSelectorEventLoop        
2023-02-04 22:50:23 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: c2d2ed1e9abf3b2e
2023-02-04 22:50:23 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2023-02-04 22:50:24 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2023-02-04 22:50:24 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2023-02-04 22:50:24 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2023-02-04 22:50:24 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2023-02-04 22:50:24 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2023-02-04 22:50:24 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6024
2023-02-04 22:50:25 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.audible.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2023-02-04 22:50:26 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.audible.com/> (referer: None)
2023-02-04 22:50:26 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2023-02-04 22:50:26 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 440,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 103231,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 2.018748,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2023, 2, 4, 20, 50, 26, 805751),
 'httpcompression/response_bytes': 1471510,
 'httpcompression/response_count': 1,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 5,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2023, 2, 4, 20, 50, 24, 787003)}
2023-02-04 22:50:26 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

it didn't gave me an eror but this is not what i want.

I used the shell command to test the xpaths and it is right.

somthing like this happend to me before but when I saved the file it worked this time nothing works.

why this is happening and how to solve this

Comment: Your xpath selectors are wrong (at the least the first one). Also try to make them shorter, it will help you in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments you selectors are not pointing to the elements you are trying to extract.

It is much easier to use element attributes and css selectors, since the paths generated by browsers are often wrong.

For example, here is how I was able to get the same information.

```
import scrapy


class AudibleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "audible"
    allowed_domains = ["www.audible.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.audible.com/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        for product in response.css('.carousel-product'):
            details = product.css('div.bc-popover-inner')
            book_title = details.xpath('.//li/h2/text()').get().strip()
            for text in details.xpath('.//li/text()'):
                if text.re(r'By:'):
                    book_author = text.get().strip()
                elif text.re(r'Length'):
                    book_len = text.get().strip()
            yield{
                'auther':book_author,
                'lenghth':book_len,
                'title':book_title,
            }
```

OUTPUT

```
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        Prince Harry The Duke of Sussex', 'lenghth': 'Length: 15 hrs and 39 mins', 'title': 'Spare'}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        James Clear', 'lenghth': 'Length: 5 hrs and 35 mins', 'title': 'Atomic Habits'}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        Jinger Vuolo, Corey Williams', 'lenghth': 'Length: 5 hrs and 49 mins', 'title': 'Becoming Free Indeed'}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        Colleen Hoover', 'lenghth': 'Length: 11 hrs and 11 mins', 'title': 'It Ends with Us'}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        Margot Hunt', 'lenghth': 'Length: 2 hrs and 52 mins', 'title': 'Tell Her Story'}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        J.K. Rowling', 'lenghth': 'Length: 8 hrs and 18 mins', 'title': "Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone, Book 1"}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        Prince Harry The Duke of Sussex', 'lenghth': 'Length: 15 hrs and 39 mins', 'title': 'Spare'}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        James Clear', 'lenghth': 'Length: 5 hrs and 35 mins', 'title': 'Atomic Habits'}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        Jinger Vuolo, Corey Williams', 'lenghth': 'Length: 5 hrs and 49 mins', 'title': 'Becoming Free Indeed'}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        Colleen Hoover', 'lenghth': 'Length: 11 hrs and 11 mins', 'title': 'It Ends with Us'}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        Margot Hunt', 'lenghth': 'Length: 2 hrs and 52 mins', 'title': 'Tell Her Story'}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        J.K. Rowling', 'lenghth': 'Length: 8 hrs and 18 mins', 'title': "Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone, Book 1"}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        Brendon Burchard', 'lenghth': 'Length: 5 hrs and 4 mins', 'title': 'The 6 Habits of Growth'}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        Jay Shetty', 'lenghth': 'Length: 10 hrs and 11 mins', 'title': '8 Rules of Love'}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        Bonnie Garmus', 'lenghth': 'Length: 11 hrs and 55 mins', 'title': 'Lessons in Chemistry'}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        David Goggins', 'lenghth': 'Length: 11 hrs and 6 mins', 'title': 'Never Finished'}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        Shelby Van Pelt', 'lenghth': 'Length: 11 hrs and 16 mins', 'title': 'Remarkably Bright Creatures'}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        Mark Manson', 'lenghth': 'Length: 5 hrs and 17 mins', 'title': 'The Subtle Art of Not Giving a F*ck'}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        Jennette McCurdy', 'lenghth': 'Length: 6 hrs and 26 mins', 'title': "I'm Glad My Mom Died"}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        Jordan B. Peterson, Norman Doidge MD - foreword', 'lenghth': 'Length: 15 hrs and 40 mins', 'title': '12 Rules for Life'}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        Stephen King', 'lenghth': 'Length: 24 hrs and 6 mins', 'title': 'Fairy Tale'}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        David Goggins', 'lenghth': 'Length: 13 hrs and 37 mins', 'title': "Can't Hurt Me"}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        Robert Greene', 'lenghth': 'Length: 23 hrs and 6 mins', 'title': '48 Laws of Power'}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        Dean Koontz', 'lenghth': 'Length: 14 hrs and 26 mins', 'title': 'The Silent Corner'}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        Matthew McConaughey', 'lenghth': 'Length: 6 hrs and 42 mins', 'title': 'Greenlights'}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        Dean Koontz', 'lenghth': 'Length: 10 hrs and 22 mins', 'title': 'The House at the End of the World'}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        Barbara Kingsolver', 'lenghth': 'Length: 21 hrs and 3 mins', 'title': 'Demon Copperhead'}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        Michelle Obama', 'lenghth': 'Length: 9 hrs and 59 mins', 'title': 'The Light We Carry'}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        Pamela Anderson', 'lenghth': 'Length: 5 hrs and 28 mins', 'title': 'Love, Pamela'}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        James Patterson, Michael B. Silver', 'lenghth': 'Length: 3 hrs and 42 mins', 'title': 'The Method'}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        Taylor Jenkins Reid', 'lenghth': 'Length: 12 hrs and 10 mins', 'title': 'The Seven Husbands of Evelyn Hugo'}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        Rick Rubin', 'lenghth': 'Length: 5 hrs and 45 mins', 'title': 'The Creative Act'}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        Dale Carnegie', 'lenghth': 'Length: 7 hrs and 15 mins', 'title': 'How to Win Friends & Influence People'}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        Bessel A. van der Kolk', 'lenghth': 'Length: 16 hrs and 15 mins', 'title': 'The Body Keeps the Score'}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        Sarah J. Maas', 'lenghth': 'Length: 16 hrs and 7 mins', 'title': 'A Court of Thorns and Roses'}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        Gabrielle Zevin', 'lenghth': 'Length: 13 hrs and 52 mins', 'title': 'Tomorrow, and Tomorrow, and Tomorrow'}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        Mel Robbins', 'lenghth': 'Length: 13 hrs and 52 mins', 'title': 'Reinvent Your Life With Mel Robbins'}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        Margot Hunt', 'lenghth': 'Length: 2 hrs and 52 mins', 'title': 'Tell Her Story'}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        Brendon Burchard', 'lenghth': 'Length: 5 hrs and 4 mins', 'title': 'The 6 Habits of Growth'}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        Robert Greene', 'lenghth': 'Length: 23 hrs and 6 mins', 'title': '48 Laws of Power'}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        Dean Koontz', 'lenghth': 'Length: 14 hrs and 26 mins', 'title': 'The Silent Corner'}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        James Patterson, Michael B. Silver', 'lenghth': 'Length: 3 hrs and 42 mins', 'title': 'The Method'}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        Mel Robbins', 'lenghth': 'Length: 3 hrs and 42 mins', 'title': 'Reinvent Your Life With Mel Robbins'}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        Margot Hunt', 'lenghth': 'Length: 2 hrs and 52 mins', 'title': 'Tell Her Story'}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        Brendon Burchard', 'lenghth': 'Length: 5 hrs and 4 mins', 'title': 'The 6 Habits of Growth'}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        Robert Greene', 'lenghth': 'Length: 23 hrs and 6 mins', 'title': '48 Laws of Power'}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        Dean Koontz', 'lenghth': 'Length: 14 hrs and 26 mins', 'title': 'The Silent Corner'}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        James Patterson, Michael B. Silver', 'lenghth': 'Length: 3 hrs and 42 mins', 'title': 'The Method'}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        Charles Kindinger', 'lenghth': 'Length: 3 hrs and 42 mins', 'title': 'Moriarty'}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        Joseph Fink, Jeffrey Cranor', 'lenghth': 'Length: 3 hrs and 42 mins', 'title': 'Unlicensed'}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        Ben Rock, Bob DeRosa', 'lenghth': 'Length: 2 hrs and 20 mins', 'title': 'Catchers'}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        Sun Tzu', 'lenghth': 'Length: 1 hr and 7 mins', 'title': 'The Art of War'}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        Diana Gabaldon', 'lenghth': 'Length: 32 hrs and 38 mins', 'title': 'Outlander'}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        Dervla McTiernan', 'lenghth': 'Length: 3 hrs and 54 mins', 'title': 'The Wrong One'}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        Kimberly Belle, Layne Fargo, Cate Holahan, and others', 'lenghth': 'Length: 8 hrs and 45 mins', 'title': 'Young Rich Widows'}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        Faith G. Harper PhD LPC-S ACS ACN', 'lenghth': 'Length: 3 hrs and 39 mins', 'title': 'Unf--k Your Brain'}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        George Orwell', 'lenghth': 'Length: 11 hrs and 22 mins', 'title': '1984'}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        Lily Chu', 'lenghth': 'Length: 12 hrs and 14 mins', 'title': 'The Comeback'}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        Anna-Lou Weatherley', 'lenghth': 'Length: 10 hrs and 51 mins', 'title': 'The Couple on Cedar Close'}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        John Scalzi', 'lenghth': 'Length: 3 hrs and 43 mins', 'title': 'Travel by Bullet'}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        Joy Ellis', 'lenghth': 'Length: 9 hrs and 46 mins', 'title': 'Their Lost Daughters'}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        Jules Barnard', 'lenghth': 'Length: 8 hrs and 20 mins', 'title': "Never Date Your Brother's Best Friend"}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        Cara Bastone', 'lenghth': 'Length: 5 hrs and 10 mins', 'title': 'Seatmate'}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        Elizabeth Edmondson', 'lenghth': 'Length: 13 hrs and 16 mins', 'title': 'Villa in Italy'}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        Randy McKinnon', 'lenghth': 'Length: 13 hrs and 16 mins', 'title': 'The Prophecy'}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        Jane Austen', 'lenghth': 'Length: 11 hrs and 35 mins', 'title': 'Pride and Prejudice'}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        Marcus Aurelius, George Long - translator, Duncan Steen - translator', 'lenghth': 'Length: 5 hrs and 9 mins', 'title': 'Meditations'}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        Viktor E. Frankl', 'lenghth': 'Length: 4 hrs and 44 mins', 'title': "Man's Search for Meaning"}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        Maggie Miller', 'lenghth': 'Length: 5 hrs and 52 mins', 'title': 'Gulf Coast Cottage'}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        Jeneva Rose', 'lenghth': 'Length: 9 hrs and 22 mins', 'title': 'One of Us Is Dead'}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        Mel Robbins', 'lenghth': 'Length: 9 hrs and 22 mins', 'title': "Here's Exactly What To Do"}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.audible.com/>
{'auther': 'By:\n                        Liv Constantine', 'lenghth': 'Length: 2 hrs and 45 mins', 'title': 'Misconception'}
2023-02-04 14:19:03 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```